# How to design Database for this situation?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database-design

I'm working a minimal game with Java and mysql. I encountered some difficulties with how to design my tables correctly. I need some advices: Let me be specific, I have 3 classes:

Node

```
 public class Node {
     private Integer id;
     private Integer position;
     private Integer foodTax;
     private Boolean hasTreasureMap;
     private Integer currentPlayer; // playerId
```

Treasure

```
 public class Treasure {
     Integer id;
     private Integer position; // nodeId
     private Integer goldValue;
```

Player

```
public class Player {
 private Integer id;
 private Integer wealth;
 private Integer strength;
 private Integer start;
 private Integer goal;
 private Integer currentPosition; // nodeId
 private Integer currentGoal; // another nodeId
 private Vector<Integer> path;
 private Vector<Integer> treasureIds;
 private int currentMoveIndex;
 Graph<Integer> telescope;
```

I'm a newbie to mysql, and database in general. I think I have to use foreign key in this case. However, I'm still vague how to implement it. Besides, there are several constraints:

1. Treasure's position is fixed.
2. Node position is fix.
3. Only player position can be changed.
4. A node can only have a player at a time.( I try to make it as simple as I can, cause if there are two players in the same node, I don't know how to handle it )

So the only foreign key here in my opinion is 'currentPlayer' id of class Node? Please correct me if I was wrong. Any idea?

Best regards,
Chan Nguyen

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store? What are you going to do with it? It's hard to help design tables when it's not clear what they'll be used for.

Comment: My map is a two dimensional array of Integer. So all position are integers. I will map this integer to a Coordinate( x, y ) when drawing. But this is not relevant to the database at all. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT's still not clear what you're trying to store, but you could have a table for Nodes:

```
Node
   id
   position
   foodTax
   hasTreasureMap
   currentPlayerID /*Refers to Player table*/

Treasure
   id
   nodeID /* refers to Node table*/
   value

Player
   id
   /*unrelated fields such as wealth, strength, start*/
   position /*refers to ID in Node*/
   currentGoal /*refers to ID in Node*/

PlayerTreasures
   playerID /* refers to Player table*/
   treasureID /* refers to Treasure table*/

Paths
   nodeID /*refers to NodeID - I assume that a path is made of Nodes*/
   sequenceInPath /*I assume that the ordering in a path matters*/
   playerID /*refers to the player who owns this path*/
```

...I have no idea what the `Telescope` is for. Again, this suggestion might not work, I'm not exactly sure what you're doing with this data.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key is just the id of another record. If a Treasure is supposed to be associated with a Node, then you can put the id of the Node in the Treasure record.

Just a suggestion on naming: Call your IDs by the table name plus "id", rather than just "id". For example, call the ID of the Node table "nodeid" (or "node_id" or something similar). Then when you put a foreign key in a table, use the same name, like your Treasure table could then have the fields (treasureid, nodeid, goldvalue). This makes it a lot easier to keep track of what your doing as the database gets more complicated. Otherwise you have to somehow keep track of the fact that "position" is a node id and so ic "currentPosition" and maybe half a dozen other names. It makes your joins obvious, like "select whatever from node join treasure on node.nodeid=treasure.nodeid".

(If you could have two foreign keys to the same table, like where your Player has a current node id and a goal node id, then you have to get a little more complicated, call them "current_nodeid" and "goal_nodeid" or some such. But its still then clear that is a nodeid and not something else, like someone else reading your code might supppose that currentGoal is a Treasure id or a total number of gold points or any of dozens of other things.)

Comment: Thanks Jay. I'll take your words for naming those columns ;)